# Bootstrap Carousel (Touch version) Indicators bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I've installed [Bootstrap Touch Carousel](https://github.com/ixisio/bootstrap-touch-carousel) which changes the current carousel only for mobile devices so it auto-overwrites the default styling.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KY5Tu/13/)

The swipe functions are working when viewing through mobile device but the problem is that carousel-indicators dissapear if I change position:

```
.carousel-indicators{bottom:-45px}
```

This is set same as in the CSS for normal devices but when viewing this through mobile, the position won't work.